# spring security : logout does not work when having long relative path

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security, jstl

In my spring security app, I have my logout button placed with the following code

```
<li><a href="<c:url value="j_spring_security_logout"/>">Log out</a></li>
```

Now when my URL is`http://localhost:8080/servletname`, logout works fine.

Even when it is `http://localhost:8080/servletname/abc` it works fine.

But when the URL is `http://localhost:8080/servletname/abc/xyz`, when I click the logout button, I get a 404 page as the page is redirected to `http://localhost:8080/servletname/abc/j_spring_security_logout`.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

">Log outsee [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/WD-html40-970708/htmlweb.html) especially part:

```
Given a base URL and a relative URL (that does not begin with a slash), a full URL is derived as follows:

If the base URL ends with a slash the full URL is derived by appending the relative URL to the base URL. For example, if the base URL is http://nosite.com/dir1/dir2/ and the relative URL is gee.html, the derived URL is http://nosite.com/dir1/dir2/gee.html.
If the base URL doesn't end with a slash, the last piece of the base URL is considered a resource, so the full URL is derived by appending the relative URL to the parent of the base URL. For example, if the base URL is http://nosite.com/dir1/dir2 and the relative URL is gee.html, the derived URL is http://nosite.com/dir1/gee.html
```

You're using relative path, make it absolute by using "/" at beginning of url:

```
<a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>">Log out</a>
```

Comment: It doesn't work..It gets redirected to http://localhost:8080/j_spring_security_logout

Comment: i think it should be `<a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout"/>">Log out</a>`

Comment: i'm glad that helped... and @Jakub, you owe me one ;)